# Is there support/extensions for evaluating TypeScript expression on a browser's console?

Tags: browser, console, typescript

The title says it: are there browsers in which I can directly evaluate TypeScript (rather than JavaScript) expressions directly in the console?

If not: do current browsers have APIs that could be used to develop plugins or extensions to do just that — integrating smoothly with the built-in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are there browsers in which I can directly evaluate TypeScript (rather than JavaScript) expressions directly in the console

No

> do current browsers have APIs that could be used to develop plugins or extensions to do just that — integrating smoothly with the built-in console

Not the built in console. But you can create a new `TypeScript console`. This would be similar to the coffescript console : https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/sample-extensions#coffeescript_console

Should be simple enough to twist that to a `TypeScript` console if you want to. Its basically this line : https://github.com/snookca/CoffeeConsole/blob/master/src/coffee-console.html#L89 that needs to point to something like `TypeString` : https://www.npmjs.org/package/typestring. Syntax highlighting is a *much* more involved problem.